# How is it possible that I'm getting a 13ms ping RTT from London to a New York IP?

Tags: networking, ping, latency

I have created a Digital Ocean - App Platform app in the New York region.

When I ping my domain, I get this IP address: `172.67.143.96` and this RTT `13.501ms`

[image]

If this IP address is actually in New York as I wanted it to be, the ping from London should be around `70ms` according to https://wondernetwork.com/pings/New%20York

What could possibly be going on?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I can tell that IP-address 172.67.143.96 is a CloudFlare IP-address and not the actual IP-address of you server.

CloudFlare in turn uses anycast or similar to direct your traffic to a nearby node.

Comment: It's so ovbious after you pointed it out :D. It makes all sense. Thank you very much!